# Try/Except not working when fetching from SQLite database

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I am bulding an app that extracts different attributes from an XML file in my iTunes library export. Since not every song has a genre, finding one per song will not always work. When the program inserts a genre into the 'Genre', it creates an automatic id

```
CREATE TABLE Genre (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name TEXT UNIQUE
);
```

The thing is, when there is no 'Genre' found in the XML file, nothing is inserted, meaning I cannot later fetch the id created by the addition of something to put it in a tabke in order to do relational queries. To stop this, I put the insert and fetch inside a try/except that would catch the

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

error when it is unable to

`cur.fetchone()[0]`

. In the except I established the genre as "No Genre" to generate the unique id for the case that there were no genre found. This, even though it catches an exception in the try block, isnt running. Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Documents\python\tracks.py in <module>
     83         cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Artist WHERE name = ? ', (genre, ))
---> 84         genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]
     85     except:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Documents\python\tracks.py in <module>
     87         cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Genre (name) VALUES ( ? )''', ( genre, ) )
     88         cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Artist WHERE name = ? ', (genre, ))
---> 89         genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]
     90 
     91 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Help! Why isn't the try/except not working?

```
    try:
        cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Genre (name) VALUES ( ? )''', ( genre, ) )
        cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Artist WHERE name = ? ', (genre, ))
        genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]
    except:
        genre = "No Genre"
        cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Genre (name) VALUES ( ? )''', ( genre, ) )
        cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Artist WHERE name = ? ', (genre, ))
        genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: try...except is for your code to try the things that are above except. If that fails, it executes code under `except`. If you put the same failed code under `except` it won't work. You exception shows that your code has a problem at line 84 (under try) and then 89 (under except). So, try...except is working. The bigger question is, why is an exception thrown. Is it possible that you got no records for the genre you were looking for?

Comment: That is true. The question is more like why is the except throwing an error aswell. The first time it runs, the genre is succsesfully added to the db, but the next song without a genre doesnt work. Why doesn't it INSERT even though the genre var is defined?

Answer (score 0):

**Okay, solution first**

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('systeminfo.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

genre = 'test'
try:
    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Genre (name) VALUES ( ? )''', ( genre, ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Artist WHERE name = ? ', (genre, ))
    genre_id = cur.fetchone()
    if genre_id is None:
        print('Select did not find any artist for {} genre'.format(genre))
    else:
        print('Select resulted in Artist ID {}'.format(genre_id[0]))
except Exception as e:
    print('Exception: {}'.format(e))
    raise Exception(e)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

See, there's a possibility that `cur.fetchone()` can result in a row or None if there is no row. So, let's do an if..then to check for None.

Here's what seems to be happening. Scroll way at the bottom of the post to find your answer.

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE Artist (
    id integer not null primary key autoincrement,
    name text,
    genre text
);

CREATE TABLE Genre (
    id integer not null primary key autoincrement,
    name text unique
);
```

**Data**

```
sqlite> select * from Artist;
Run Time: real 0.000 user 0.000086 sys 0.000054
sqlite> select * from Genre;
Run Time: real 0.000 user 0.000092 sys 0.000064
sqlite>
```

Basically, there's no data.

**Your code**

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('systeminfo.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

genre = 'test'
try:
    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Genre (name) VALUES ( ? )''', ( genre, ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Artist WHERE name = ? ', (genre, ))
    genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]
except:
    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Genre (name) VALUES ( ? )''', ( genre, ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Artist WHERE name = ? ', (genre, ))
    genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

**Issue**

Your errors are happening in 2 places. In your `try` block, there's an error at `genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]`. Once the error is hit, the control goes to `except` block. In that block, the code is repeated. That means, the error is repeated. In that block, there is no error handling because it IS error handling. So, python throws another error in except block for the same thing `genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]`.

**Clean up the issue**

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('systeminfo.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

genre = 'test'
try:
    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Genre (name) VALUES ( ? )''', ( genre, ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Artist WHERE name = ? ', (genre, ))
    genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]
except Exception as e:
    print('Exception: {}'.format(e))

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Alright. In `except` we want to handle the exception and perhaps print out the exception. So, we will use `except Exception as e`. Now, error information is in `e`. We print that out and that's it.

```
$ python myfile.py
Exception: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

**But what if I want to show where the error is?**

Add `raise Exception(e)` right under `print('Exception: {}'.format(e))`. So, the result becomes this:

```
$ python myfile.py
Exception: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testy.py", line 9, in <module>
    genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testy.py", line 12, in <module>
    raise Exception(e)
Exception: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

That `raise` statement lists out on the screen where issue happened.

Comment: But what if I want to have a Genre in the Genre table called "No Genre" as to not repeat a NULL id repeated multiple times? Here is the code:

Comment: @SalomønC.S. can you edit your post and add your code? You can easily do so by `cur.execute('insert or ignore into Genre (name) VALUES ( ? )', ( 'No Genre', ) )` and then `cur.execute("update Artists set Genre = 'No Genre' where Genre is null")`